# base_url do Codeigniter 3 alterando link de chamada do css e js

Tags: php, bootstrap-3, codeigniter-3

Boa tarde, pessoal! Estou fazendo um site com uma página de inscrição que usa codeigniter e bootstrap, mas estou tendo um problema:

O CSS e o JS carregam normalmente, mas quando faço uma inscrição e redireciono página para aparecer uma mensagem de sucesso, todos os CSS e JS não são mais chamados no local certo e a página desconfigura.

Ex.: deveria ser carregado o arquivo css através do seguinte link:

"h ttp://localhost/teste/assets/css/inscricao.css"

mas quando o redirecionamento é feito, ele passa a ser chamado no seguinte link:

"http://localhost/teste/inscricao/assets/css/inscricao.css"

Ou seja, não é mais chamado no local correto. E de onde apareceu "/inscrição/", no meio do link, na chamada do arquivo, assim do nada?

Estou usando a função base_url(), que está configurada da seguinte maneira:

```
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/teste/';
```

No html:

```
    <link href="<?php base_url(); ?>assets/css/inscricao.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**DETALHE**: se no html eu tirar o base_url(); e no lugar colocar diretamente "http://localhost/teste/", esse problema não acontecerá.

**OBS**: esse redirecionamento que faço é através de URI Routing do Codeigniter.

*Código do controlador*:

```
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Inscricao extends CI_Controller {

        public function index($indice=null)
        {
            $this->load->view('estrutura/header');
            $this->load->view('estrutura/menu');

            if($indice==1){
                $this->load->view('estrutura/msg_sucesso');
            } else if($indice==2){
                $this->load->view('estrutura/msg_erro');
            }

            $this->load->view('inscricao');
            $this->load->view('estrutura/footer');
        }

            public function inscrever(){
                $data['nome'] = $this->input->post('nome');
                $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');

               if($this->db->insert('alunos',$data)){
                      redirect('inscricao/1');
               } else{
                   redirect('inscricao/2');
               }
           }
    }
```

No arquivo "routes.php", está assim:

```
    $route['inscricao/(:num)'] = 'inscricao/index/$1';
```

Alguém que possa me ajudar, por favor? O que há de errado?
Agradeço, desde já, a quem puder ajudar! =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, tente isso:

$config['base_url'] = '';

ou

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost'

e coloque um echo no base_url: 
echo base_url('assets/css/inscricao.css');

Comment: Oi! Fiz as alterações e agora está dando certo. Fico muito agradecido, pois me ajudou bastante! Até mais! ;)